# slc start giving error Error: pm failed, exit with status 1

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, strongloop

I'm running a nodeapp on `Centos6` `AWS ec2` machine.
I've installed `strongloop` using this command `npm install -g strongloop`.

`slc -h` is available for me.

I'm having `express.js` application my application start point is in `/app_path/bin/www`
for both `slc start` and `slc start www` command in `/app_path/bin/` giving me following error

`Error: pm failed, exit with status 1`

Comment: I've seen this error when some modules (like sqlite) could not be installed - can you install the module (`npm i sqlite3`) if it does not help you might want to run in debug mode `DEBUG=* slc start >debug.log 2>&1` and see the details